# npm install stuck at fetchMetadata on windows 7

Tags: node.js, apache, powershell, npm-install, laravel-mix

I am working with Laravel 5.4, and i desire to use Laravel mix for my asset compilation. I have followed the steps required to work with this which is to install node and npm.

Below is my result for running **node -v** and **npm -v** on the command line.
[image]

Therefore i have **node** and **npm** installed.

The next step i took was to navigate to my project folder and run

> npm intall --no-bin-links

as recommended for windows user in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#installation), below is the result i got
[image]

And it's been like this for hours now. What could be the cause? Has anyone experienced this before?

I am running this on **Apache server**.

Comment: Maybe there is no connection with the NPM server. Do you have a internet connection and are the right firewall ports open. Did you try to install an other package. Are there error messages?

Comment: @Yoruba, I have an internet connection, and there are no errors messages.

Comment: You can try to run NPM as admin and see what happens. And try an other folder maybe there a some permissions on the current folder.